# Python: minimize multiple functions with multiple variables

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I am trying to minimize 2 functions with 2 variables at the same time.
I have a set of data and 2 equations like:

```
B1 = 4
P1 = 6
G1 = 2
E1 = 3

F1 = B - G - E = -1
F2 = P - G - E = 1
```

Given a new `B2 = 5` and `P2 = 6` I would like to calculate the variables G2, E2 so that the difference between the old values F1 = -1 and F2 = 1 and the new values F3 and F4 are minimized:

```
B2 = 5
P2 = 6
G2 = ?
E2 = ?

F3 = B2 - G2 - E2 ---> as close as possible to F1
F4 = P2 - G2 - E2 ---> as close as possible to F2
```

I was trying:

```
   def diff(param):
        G2, E2 = param  
        return abs(B1 - G2 - E2 - F1)

    x0 = [2,2]
    res = minimize(diff, x0)
```

This resolve properly the minimization that gives F3 = F1 = -1, but does not solve my intention to also minimize the difference (F4 - F2). 
Do you know how to include also the second minimization problem?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if my approach is too naive (it probably is, to be honest), but considering that you want to minimize two differences, meaning that each difference must tend to zero, then why don't you try to minimize the sum of the differences? This sum should also tend to zero. It would look like that:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def diff(x):
    G2, E2 = x
    return (abs(B2 - G2 - E2 - F1 + P2 - G2 - E2 - F2))


B1 = 4
P1 = 6
G1 = 2
E1 = 3
F1 = B1 - G1 - E1
F2 = P1 - G1 - E1
B2 = 5
P2 = 6
res = minimize(diff, x0=(1, 1))
```

`res.x` returns `[2.75, 2.75]`, which gives `F3 = -0.5`, `F4 = 0.5`.